# Force HTTP loading of Gmail

Tags: google-chrome, gmail, https

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Log into Gmail without SSL](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/21467/log-into-gmail-without-ssl)

I want Gmail to open in HTTP mode in Chrome. I don't care about security or man-in-the middle stuff; who would want to read my emails anyway?

I have set the "Don't always use HTTPS" option in the settings page, but no avail.

How do I do this?

Comment: Changing manually `https` to `http` works in firefox but not in chrome !! . I have this problem too . I always go to gmail with firefox :(.

Comment: That sounds like a good compromise!
My primary browser is Opera, I use chrome only for gmail, so I'll simply use FF instead!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to their blog ([http://blog.chromium.org/2011/06/new-chromium-security-features-june.html)](http://blog.chromium.org/2011/06/new-chromium-security-features-june.html), Chrome will use HTTPS for Gmail always. There is no turning it off.

> As of Chromium 13, all connections to Gmail will be over HTTPS. This includes the initial navigation even if the user types “gmail.com” or “mail.google.com” into the URL bar without an https:// prefix, which defends against sslstrip-type attacks.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution in **firefox** that don't need to changin address bar as in the comment I said

> Changing manually https to http works in firefox but not in chrome !! . I have this problem too . I always go to gmail with firefox

**In firefox you should go to `http://gmail.com` then log in to gmail with it.**

if you log in gmail from  http://google.com it goes to gmail with `HTTPS` and ...

Answer (score -1):

HTTPS will not noticeably affect the speed of browsing, on any machine likely to support Chrome.

Comment: Incorrect! Whatever you do , encryption will happen on the browser, and will eat up cycles and cause latency. Also SSL channels do not compress on the fly, so bandwidth is wasted.

Comment: I never said there was no impact, but are you seriously suggesting that there's a huge noticeable impact of HTTPS -v- HTTP? The time and overhead of switching to a different browser I'm sure outweighs the 'delays'.

Comment: Here you have some information: http://stackoverflow.com/a/149445/1275853

Comment: Firefox seems way faster in HTTP, I tried! I'll measure and make sure